# Error when calling variables in a function in R

Tags: r, debugging

I want to put a series of steps in a function. They work fine outside of a function, with manually defined arguments (i.e. `x_var = Education`, `y_var = Happiness`, `polynom = 5`). However, placing them within a function returns: `Error: id variables not found in data: x_var, y_var`

```
my.func <- function(train.dat,polynom,x_var,y_var){

## <truncated; the parts above this work even in a function> 

# fitted values of Y for each X, for each model
long.fit.dat <- reshape2::melt(lm.fit.dat,
                               id.vars = c("x_var", "y_var"),
                               measure.vars = c(paste0("x", 1:polynom)),  
                               variable.name = "Polynomial", 
                               value.name = "y.fit")

# ggplot
ggplot(long.fit.dat, aes(x = x_var, y = y_var, 
                         color = Polynomial)) + 
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = y.fit), size = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Polynomial) + 
  theme_bw()


# Model fit error on training set (mse.train)

y.fit <- cbind( lm.fit.dat[c(3:ncol(lm.fit.dat))] )     # 3: because first 2 columns are x_var and y_var   

mse.train <- colMeans((y.fit - train.dat$y_var)^2) 

mse.dat <- data.frame(MSE = mse.train,
                      Powers = paste0("X", 1:polynom))

# ggplot of Powers by MSE for training data  
  ggplot(mse.dat, aes(x = Powers, y = MSE, group = 1)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw()
  
mse.train

} # end of function

# test the function
my.func(train.dat,5,Education,Happiness)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. You are trying to use *non-standard evaluation* by allowing the user to pass column names into your function, but this is a fairly advanced topic in R. This syntax often seems natural to new R users because it is used extensively in tidyverse functions, but there's actually quite a lot of programming with the language going on inside the tidyverse to allow this to work properly, and it can be difficult to make this kind of approach work in your own functions.

In the absence of a reproducible example, I will create one here to try to show what's going on. Let's start by creating a simple data frame:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, 
                 color = c("red", "green", "red", "green", "red"), 
                 values1 = 10:14, 
                 values2 = 101:105)

df
#>   id color values1 values2
#> 1  1   red      10     101
#> 2  2 green      11     102
#> 3  3   red      12     103
#> 4  4 green      13     104
#> 5  5   red      14     105
```

Note that we can use `reshape2::melt` to reshape this into long format:

```
reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = c("id", "color"))
#>    id color variable value
#> 1   1   red  values1    10
#> 2   2 green  values1    11
#> 3   3   red  values1    12
#> 4   4 green  values1    13
#> 5   5   red  values1    14
#> 6   1   red  values2   101
#> 7   2 green  values2   102
#> 8   3   red  values2   103
#> 9   4 green  values2   104
#> 10  5   red  values2   105
```

Now suppose we wanted to do that inside a function that takes unquoted variable names. Let's try your approach first:

```
my.func1 <- function(data, x_var, y_var) {
  reshape2::melt(data = data, id.vars = c("x_var", "y_var"))
}

my.func1(df, id, color)
#> Error: id variables not found in data: x_var, y_var
```

The error here is because the `id.vars` argument of `melt` takes strings as the names of the columns, and you have given it the literal strings `"x_var"` and `"y_var"`. But our data frame doesn't *have* columns called `"x_var"` or `"y_var"`, so `melt` throws an error.

What if we just pass `x_var` and `y_var` directly?

```r
my.func2 <- function(data, x_var, y_var) {
  reshape2::melt(data = data, id.vars = c(x_var, y_var))
}

my.func2(df, id, color)
#> Error in melt_check(data, id.vars, measure.vars, variable.name, value.name): 
#> object 'id' not found
```

The problem now is that `melt` is trying to evaluate our variables instead of using them as strings, so it gives us a different error.

To fix this, we want to convert the names we passed into the function as character strings. We can do this with `deparse(substitute(x_var))`:

```r
my.func3 <- function(data, x_var, y_var) {
  reshape2::melt(data = data, 
                 id.vars = c(deparse(substitute(x_var)), 
                             deparse(substitute(y_var))))
}

my.func3(df, id, color)
#>    id color variable value
#> 1   1   red  values1    10
#> 2   2 green  values1    11
#> 3   3   red  values1    12
#> 4   4 green  values1    13
#> 5   5   red  values1    14
#> 6   1   red  values2   101
#> 7   2 green  values2   102
#> 8   3   red  values2   103
#> 9   4 green  values2   104
#> 10  5   red  values2   105
```

So we can safely `melt` our data frame. Unfortunately, that's not the end of the story. Look what happens when we try to use `ggplot` after this:

```r
my.func4 <- function(data, x_var, y_var) {
  long_df <- reshape2::melt(data = data, 
                            id.vars = c(deparse(substitute(x_var)), 
                                        deparse(substitute(y_var))))
  
  ggplot(long_df, aes(x = x_var, y = y_var)) + 
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  theme_bw()
}

my.func4(df, id, color)
#> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): object 'id' not found
```

Now `ggplot` is trying to evaluate our variables inside `aes` and causing a new error. We want ggplot to "swap" `x_var` for `id` and `y_var` for `color`. We do that by ensuring that these are recognised as symbols and evaluated inside `ggplot`. We do this by wrapping them in `ensym` and evaluating them with the `!!` operator inside ggplot:

```r
my.func5 <- function(data, x_var, y_var) {
  long_df <- reshape2::melt(data = data, 
                            id.vars = c(deparse(substitute(x_var)), 
                                        deparse(substitute(y_var))))
  x_var <- ensym(x_var)
  y_var <- ensym(y_var)
  
  ggplot(long_df, aes(x = !!x_var, y = !!y_var)) + 
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  theme_bw()
}
```

So this should now produce a plot without complaint:

```r
my.func5(df, id, color)
```

[image]